# A limerick riddle. Provides clues to song titles that have a word in common

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, limerick, cryptic-clues

> You might think I'm broke, but then
>
> I'm a singer and sound like a hen
>
> You can count on me
>
> I'm a tramp you see
>
> So I'll sing you the blues once again.

The above limerick conceals six song titles. Can you find all six and say what word they have in common?

Note: In order to make the limerick rhyme, I've had to take a few liberties but I think all the song titles are perfectly discoverable once you have guessed the common word. Some clues are cryptic and some are more straightforward.

Comment: How about "The lady is a tramp" sang by Sinatra as a clue/partial answer?

Comment: @MarekOleszczuk -  Correct +1. I'll up-vote every correct suggestion and give the green tick to whoever finally sets out the most up-voted answer that also has the word and six convincing song-titles that fit the clues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the comment from Marek Oleszczuk got the keyword, here are my contributions for the other lines:

1/ You might think I'm broke, but then

> Lady in Red by Chris de Burgh. If you are "in the red", financially, you have a negative balance, and being broke is a similar state.

2a/ I'm a singer...

> Lady Madonna by the Beatles. Madonna is of course, among her other talents, a popular singer.

2b/ ...and sound like a hen

> Lay Lady Lay by Bob Dylan (courtesy of @TroyAndAbed). Hens lay eggs.

3/ You can count on me

> Three times a Lady by the Commodores. The line from the song containing the title is "you're once, twice, three times a lady", hence the counting.

4/ I'm a tramp you see

> The Lady is a Tramp by Frank Sinatra (taken from comments). This is self-explanatory, I think.

5/ So I'll sing you the blues once again.

> Lady sings the blues by Billie Holiday. Again this is self-explanatory.

The key word is of course

> Lady. Each clue is told from the point of view of the particular Lady as designated in the song title, although sometimes interpreted differently (cryptically even) to the original.

Comment: Lady sings the Blues - Billie Holiday (1956)

Comment: @Spacemonkey: thanks, I'd just typed that it when I got your comment, but I think technically you were faster.

Comment: @Fillet Sounds like a Lady ? Living in America ?

Comment: Just 2b and 3 to get now. There is a much better one for 3 (IMO of course). You can't always count on your luck!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, done. I'm stuck, but here's a bonus song title: D'Arbanville-Godiva-Marmelade

Comment: 2b) Bob Dylan - Lay Lady Lay

Comment: @TroyAndAbed - Haha - correct. Just clue #3  to go.

Comment: (Once, Twice), Three times a lady for #3?

Comment: @Fillet - correct! Now all you have to do is complete your answer with that (if you agree with me). As promised, I'll wait to see if anyone gets more up-votes but they'll have to be clever!

Comment: I appreciate that this answer may have the correct songs, but the connections don't make sense to me. These are not lyrics in the song, nor are they the song title. Can you add a little explanation for how you arrived at each?

Comment: @IanMacDonald - I added some explanations as best I could. If anything isn't clear for a particular line, feel free to ask again.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I agree with #3. Of course, if anyone cared, that was also the answer to my "bonus" song title, with 3 more song Ladys.

Comment: :) It's nice to see that someone got this solved! Some of these I never heard, so it's good to get to know something new in life, heh. You got my upvote. Oh! And on my way back from job I was thinking of 'Dude looks like a lady' by Aerosmith :)

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess here:

You might think I'm broke, but then

> Money, money, money by ABBA

You can count on me

> Lean On Me by Bill Withers

P.S. Now I have these songs singing in my head!

Comment: There is no common word.

Comment: As KonradGajewski says - All six titles all have to contain a word in common.